# Upgrading to Ruby 2.0, overwrite executables without prompt

Tags: ruby, linux

When upgrading from ruby 1.9.3 to ruby 2.0 on linux (at least 12.04) you get an unexpected prompt.

```
rdoc's executable "rdoc" conflicts with /path/bin/rdoc
Overwrite the executable? [yN]
```

It works fine to overwrite it manually but I'm looking for a way that my scripts will auto reply yes without halting.

Just found this issue on [rubygems from a year ago](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/280).  I'm using `gem install` in a script so I think I can somewhat easily add `yes | gem install`

Edit:
Tried `yes | gem install rdoc` but it fails with:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rdoc:
"rdoc" from rdoc conflicts with /usr/local/rubies/2.0.0-p0/bin/rdoc
```

Comment: `yes | the-command` though I'm sure there's a much better way. What command are you using to upgrade?

Comment: Having the same problem in a Dockerfile. `yes | the-command` doesn't work for me...

Comment: I eventually found a way around that that didn't require this install.

Answer (score 3):

You can prepend

```
 yes |
```

yes just enters y over and over again, which gets piped to to standard input.

(thanks @adamdunson)

Answer (score 2):

`--force` worked for me:

`gem install --force rdoc`

Disclaimer: this is not what `--force` is for, and I don't know why `yes |` doesn't work.

Comment: although you don't say whether to choose "yes" or "no" `[yN]`, I chose 'N'. Result: `ERROR:  Error installing rdoc:
        "rdoc" from rdoc conflicts with C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/rdoc`

_(the Install continues and finishes.)_   Then **at my user prompt, I typed your fix**:   `C:\Users\Owner>gem install --force rdoc
Successfully installed rdoc-5.1.0
Parsing documentation for rdoc-5.1.0
Installing ri documentation for rdoc-5.1.0
Done installing documentation for rdoc after 15 seconds
1 gem installed` So I believe it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

For me with Ubuntu and Ruby 2.0 the yes | prepend solution as described above did NOT work as described in my automated build script (using sprinkle gem).

I therefore added a step to the build script to rename (in my case) /usr/local/bin/rdoc and /usr/local/bin/ri before the install is executed.

Consequently the install recreates these files without the pesky prompt which I just couldnt somehow seem to avoid. Personally I think the suggestion at https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/280 is a good one although this doesnt seem to have been embraced by the community with open arms.

My solution is a somewhat crude workaround but may help others until there is a more elegant fix.

Comment: Had this same problem with my Sprinkle scripts, your suggestion worked for me. Thx

Answer (score 0):

actually, you shouldn't say yes. [This is currently a bug right now for Ruby 2.0](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5060). My own fix (which I do go with, anyway, even if this is not a problem!) is to use a gemset handler (I'm using rbenv-gemset, with rbenv right now).

Answer (score 0):

Prefixing `yes |` did not work in my case (rubygems verifies that input is tty). What works for me:

```
expect <<-DONE
    set timeout -1
    spawn gem update
    expect {
        "Overwrite the executable?" { send -- "y\r"; exp_continue }
        eof
    }
DONE
```